# Sharing or exporting music with Sibelius First

Tags: sibelius

I've just finished a composition and I am trying to share the score as a video. When I open the export tab, I cannot export the score as a video; the button is grey and will not let me click it. I also tried the share tab, but I have the same issue when sharing to youtube or facebook. How can I get a video of my score with playback?

Perhaps this is a feature not enabled in Sibelius First?

Comment: Have you installed Sibelius Sounds? The "export audio and video" options don't work with other sound playback devices. (Warning, if you didn't buy the physical product and install it from the DVDs, Sibelius Sounds is a HUGE internet download, and you need about 60 or 70Gb of free disk space to install it!) Also, IIRC the "share to youtube etc" option has been broken for a long time in all version of Sibelius, but if you can export a video, you can then upload it to a social media site yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If Export Video is an option in your Sibelius First File Menu, the function works.   (It was actually added to Sibelius First before full Sibelius got it!)

This sounds as if you either don't have the Sounds installed or haven't selected them for playback.

Comment: i'll have a look

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this feature on Sibelius first does work.

You could download just a standard screen recorder which would do the same job.